# How to add key value pair to objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am supposed to add a new key value pair of 'family: true' to each object. I am also supposed to use the forEach method. My code adds 'family: true' to the end of the array but I don't think that's what I am meant to do.

Here is the array:

```
var goodPeople = [{name: 'George'}, {name: 'Randi'}, {name: 'Lindsey'}]
```

My code:

```
goodPeople.forEach(function(){
  goodPeople.push({family:true});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn how to use forEach - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```
goodPeople.forEach(function(item){
    item.family = true;
});
```

in each iteration, `item` is one of the `objects` in the Array

there, you can add a key/value pair as you call it to each `item` in the `Array`, one at a time

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the elements of the array which are objects, then assign the property to each.

```
goodPeople.forEach(function(element){
 element.family = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` or `map` depending if you want to mutate the original array.

With ForEach and ES6:

```
goodPeople.forEach(i => { i.family = true });
```

If you don't want to mutate the original array you can use map:

```
var familyGoodPeople = goodPeople.map(i => Object.assign({}, i, {family: true }))
```